# The requested URL xxxx.tgz was not found on this server

Tags: html, apache

I was trying to create a link that allow user to download file from my server but I got "xxx.tgz what not found on this server" error.

My code is very simple:

```
<a href="/var/www/ci/cilog/dir/test.tgz">test.tgz</a><br>
```

When I click the link, it will show the "test.tgz was not found on this server" error.

Sorry for repost this question again but none of the posted solution works for me. I tried to changed the default file in the apache2 folder but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the path on your *server* in your web address.  The webserver thinks a certain folder is its root, and doesn't expose any other folders.

For example, this site is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996344`, not `/var/www/stackoverflow/questions` (I know that's not how this site works, but it's just an example).

The path needs to be the web root, not a server path.

Assuming `/var/www` is your webroot.

```
<a href="http://yourpage/ci/cilog/dir/test.tgz">test.tgz</a><br>
```

Or, you can use `/` to point to the root of your website:

```
<a href="/ci/cilog/dir/test.tgz">test.tgz</a><br>
```